# How to output javascript string contains quotes?

Tags: javascript

The final output I'm trying to achieve is:

```
<li data="["a", "b", "c"]">title</li>
```

I already have the variable:

```
var string = '["a", "b", "c"]';
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
'<li data='+string+'>'
```

Another try, still not working, but closer:

```
var string = '\"[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]\"'

'<li data='+string+'>'
```

output:

```
<li data="[" a", "b", "c"]">title</li>
```

There is a space before "a"

```
var string = "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"; 
var a = '<li data='+string+'>title</li>'; 
document.write(a);
```

Comment: Please include your code, how are you getting a space give your current still not working but closer output?

Comment: Hi, 
var string = "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]";
var a = '<li data='+string+'>title</li>';
document.write(a);

Comment: var string = "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"; 
var a = '<li data=\''+string+'\'>title</li>'; 
document.write(a);

Comment: Thanks! Elliott, Finally, it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"; 
var a = '<li data=\''+string+'\'>title</li>'; 
document.write(a);
```

But those quotes near the "[" and "]" look off in what you say you want to achieve.

Comment: @ttyy updated answer based on your comment above - also verified in firebug, where I copied this <li data="[&quot;a&quot;, &quot;b&quot;, &quot;c&quot;]">title</li>